# Find X-value position of a label inside a view in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, frame, difference, xvalue

I want to calculate the distance between `x-value` of two squares positioned in a view.

I did not work because in the frame there is also the `y-value` and do not know how to select only one.
how can I add the `x-values` from the position of the squares?

```
var redSquare: UIView = UIView()
var blueSquare: UIView = UIView()
var difference : Double = 0.0

func calc() {
difference = redSquare.frame - blueSquare.frame  
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
difference = Double(redSquare.frame.origin.x - blueSquare.frame.origin.x)
```

Comment: You should really use `CGRectGetMinX(redSquare.frame)`. CGRects can actually have negative width and height so the top left of it may not always be its origin.